# Sequel Pro: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) using mariadb installed via homebrew

Tags: laravel, mariadb, homebrew, sequelpro, valet

I'm trying to set up a wordpress environment. Using homebrew I've installed laravel valet and mariadb, and am using sequel pro to manage databases.

Right now, I can start mariadb using `brew services start mariadb`.

However, when I go to sequel pro and enter 127.0.0.1 and username: root for my credentials, I get the error "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)"

I can't figure out where my issue is. Can anybody help me troubleshoot?

Comment: Check the "bind" setting in my.cnf.  Try to connect to `localhost` instead of that IP.

Comment: Can you connect to the database from the command line (with `mariadb -u root -p`)?

Comment: Rick, when I try that I get: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)". @ortomala-lokni When I try that command it says "command not found: mariadb".